# Can you loop Dash dropdown entries?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a dropdown list with around 600 entries. Is there a way to write out the entries with out writing every line out. Like this:

```
dcc.Dropdown(
            id='select-stat-dropdown',
            options=[{'label': labels[0], 'value': values[0]},
                     {'label': labels[1], 'value': values[1]},
                     {'label': labels[2], 'value': values[2]},
                     {'label': labels[3], 'value': values[3]},
                     {'label': labels[4], 'value': values[4]},
                     {'label': labels[5], 'value': values[5]},
                     {'label': labels[6], 'value': values[6]},
...
```

I have a list for every label and value:

```
values = list(playersDF)
label = []
```

Is there a way to implement a loop to write them out for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a list comprehension to create the variable `options`

```
options = [{'label': labels[i], 'value':values[i]} for i in range(len(labels))]
```

and then pass this to the `options` parameter:

```
dcc.Dropdown(
    id='select-stat-dropdown',
    options=options
    ...
)
```

Comment: Writing C in Python that is

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really overcomplicating things.

Comment: @GBN you're welcome - glad my answer helped!

Comment: @GBN Please also look at `zip` in Python to rewrite the comprehension. might also help in the future

Comment: @Neither Just watched a video on it thanks for the advice :)